# How to manipulate `DateTime()` output?

Tags: php

Right now, for the command:

```
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

my output is:

`Mar 10, 2015 17:16:21 -0400`

How can I edit the code to make it the following output:

`Mar 10, 2015 17:16:21 -0500`

Comment: So you want it to print an incorrect time zone?

Comment: yes, thats what I want

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: not sure I understood that manual. isn't there a way to simply write somewhere a `-1` deduction, in order to change it?

Comment: exactly, you just need to set the timezone on your DateTime object. Then you could use DateInterval class to calculate date/time differences. The php manual is clear enough to understand.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like there's no way to create a time zone based on an offset like `-0500`. The constructor for `DateTimeZone` just takes names like `US/Eastern`.

Comment: But this changes the hour too. how can I change ONLY the gmt value?

Answer (score 2):

`new DateTime()` creates a new DateTime using your local server time, e.g. set in your php.ini or depending on your servers OS.

Here it is -4 hours to Greenwich meantime.

Set the desired timezone, e.g.:

```
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
```